# Are pullbacks of regular epimorphisms in an additive category always epic?

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

Fix a additive category $\mathsf C$ (that is to say, $\mathsf C$ admits an additive structure and has a zero object all biproducts). Given four morphisms in $\mathsf C$ as follows:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
x @>{\psi}>> a\\
@V{\phi}VV @VV{f}V \\
b @>>{g}> c
\end{CD}$$

Suppose $(\psi,\phi)$ is a pullback of $(f,g)$ and that $f\equiv\text{coker}(\ker f)$. Can we deduce that $\phi$ is also epic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[t]$ as a graded ring with $|t|=1$, and let $D$ be the category of graded $R$-modules. Define the objects $a=R$, $k=(t^2)\subset R$, $c=R/(t^2)$, and $b=(t)/(t^2)\subset c$ in $D$.  Let $C$ be the full subcategory of $D$ spanned by finite direct sums of the objects $a$, $k$, $c$, and $b$.

Note that there is an obvious inclusion map $k\to a$ whose cokernel is a regular epimorphism $f:a\to c$.  Let $g:b\to c$ be the inclusion map.  Now suppose $x$ is any object of $C$ and you have maps $\psi:x\to a$ and $\phi:x\to b$ such that $f\psi=g\phi$.  Note that there are no nonzero maps from any of $a$, $k$, or $c$ to $b$.  So $\phi$ must vanish on all the summands of $a$, $k$ and $c$ in the object $x$.  On the other hand, there are no nonzero maps from $b$ to $a$, so $\psi$ must vanish on all the summands of $b$ in the object $x$.  Since $g$ is injective, this means that $\phi$ must also vanish on all the summands of $b$ in $x$.  Thus $\phi=0$.

From the paragraph above, it is now easy to see that $x=k$ with $\psi:x\to a$ the inclusion map and $\phi:x\to b$ the $0$ map is a pullback of $a$ and $b$ over $c$ in $C$.  The map $\phi$ for this pullback is not epic.

More generally, you can get a similar counterexample whenever you have an abelian category with a short exact sequence $0\to k\to a\to c\to 0$ and a subobject $b\to c$ such that there are no nonzero maps from $k$, $a$, or $c$ to $b$ and no nonzero maps from $b$ to $a$.

Comment: Thank you. Your construction of $C$ is genius.

Comment: Generally you want to find counterexamples to statements like these by taking subcategories of module categories.  And if you want there to be very few maps between your objects, a great way to accomplish that is to put a grading on your modules.

Comment: I see. That's very heuristic.

Comment: In particular, the way I came up with this example is that I started by thinking about examples of short exact sequences $0\to k\to a\to c\to 0$ and maps $b\to c$ of modules such that the pullback is not a direct sum of copies of $k$, $a$, $b$, and $c$.  This means that the pullback as a module will not be in the additive subcategory they generate, and so there is some hope that the pullback in that subcategory won't behave nicely.  The tricky part is then guaranteeing that a pullback nevertheless exists in the additive subcategory they generate, and does not map onto all of $b$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration.